# Photoshop change displace settings without relinking map

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When updating the Displace settings applied to a smart object, it prompts to reselect the displacement map. Is there a way to change these settings without needing to select a displacement map every time?

[image: Text]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't think there is any way of doing this using the displacement filter - it's programmed to prompt you to select the displacement image file each time.  Perhaps it could be scripted, but I'm no scripting expert.